# SSIS and specflow

Tags: c#, ssis, specflow

I wanted to know ,

I have a ssis package which can
1) read multiple input files 
2) store the data from files to dB 
3) archive the input files

I have to write functional test using specflow

One of my test case is : 
To check the row count in the table in dB to be equal the summation of all lines in each input file read.

I am not sure how I can achieve this. Can anyone help me in :

how to get the summation of lines in each file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have doubt whether my senario is correct . coz , when i run the ssis package , the files will b moved to acheive folder. So how do i consider the input files

Comment: Why do you need to work that out? Can't you just use a set of input  files which have a known number of lines in the tests? Then you will know what the count should be after they have run.

Answer (score 0):

> To check the row count in the table in dB 
>   Add a variable to your SSIS package, named something like iRowCount. 
>   In the Data Flow Task where DB is the source, add a RowCount control, and assign the value to variable iRowCount.
>
> to be equal the summation of all lines in each input file read. 
>   Same concept, another two variables, named something like iFilesRowCount and iFilesRowCountTotal.
>   Then you'll have to pull off in each data pump a RowCount control, assigning the value to iFilesRowCount.  Then outside of each data pump a script task that does an iFilesRowCount = iFilesRowCount + iFilesRowCountTotal.

Then somewhere towards the bottom a script task to perform the comparison between iRowCount (db) and iFilesRowCountTotal, and in the arrows exiting that task create precedence constraints to pull off a 'True' path and 'False' path.

Comment: I found the answer.. I cant use the ssis package to go this.. I m writing specflow to test the package. I used a data table n got the num of lines.  N then i compared